# Laravel 4 controller method call from Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, controller, laravel-4

Since I am by no means an Ajax guru, I have come here to see if someone could lead me in the right direction to look for some information on what I am trying to do. I have scoured SO looking for information but either I don't understand what I am reading, or it's just not what I am looking to do. Honestly, I don't know if what I am trying to do is even possible, so yeah...

Basically, what I am trying to accomplish is putting my application in to maintenance mode from the admin section of my site. I am using a jQuery .click() function to update a #div, but I want to also call a function from a controller at the same time.

So here goes...

My jQuery right now is:

```
$('#on').click(function () {
    $('#turnedon').addClass('green');
    $.cookie('maint', 'Maintenance', {
        expires: 365
    });
    //alert('You have put the app in maintenance mode.');
    $.ajax({
        method: 'get',      // Should I use post? or get? I am just wanting to run the function when the .click() function is run
        url: '/admins',     // Not sure what should be used for url since I just want to call a function
        error: function(e){
            alert( 'Error ' + e );
            }
        });         
});
```

I am not sure whether I should use GET or POST for the method since I am just calling the method from the controller.

The function I am calling in my controller:

```
public function getMaintenanceOn()
{
  if(Request::ajax()) {
    Artisan::call('down');
  }
}
```

And in my routes:

```
Route::get('/admins', array('uses' => 'AdminController@getMaintenanceOn'));
```

I have also set in my global.php file that only admins can access the site when it's in maintenance mode. If I put the application down using the terminal, I can still access everything as an admin like I need to, but I would rather like to be able to put the app in maintenance mode without having to go in and change routes on the hosting files.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a problem in your javascript, here, the `$.cookie` gave me an error, but removing it all worked fine. This is what I did to test:

A route:

```
Route::get('admins', function() 
{
    Log::info("route!");

    if (Request::ajax()) {
        Log::info("ajax");

        Artisan::call('down');
    }
});
```

A button:

`enter code here`Shut down

And the javascript without the cookie:

```
<script>

    $('#on').click(function () {
        alert('You have put the app in maintenance mode.');
        $('#turnedon').addClass('green');
        $.ajax({
            method: 'get',      // Should I use post? or get? I am just wanting to run the function when the .click() function is run
            url: '/admins',     // Not sure what should be used for url since I just want to call a function
            error: function(e){
                alert( 'Error ' + e );
                }
            });         
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Antonio. So from what I get in your test, when the javascript function is executed, I should see in my log file route! (which I do), but if it's requested by an ajax call, I should see ajax?

Comment: Yes, I see both in my log here and the application shuts down after that.

Comment: Strange. I am only seeing the route! in my log and the application doesn't shut down on my end. I want to return to the /admins view which is where I shut the app down from. It returns to me a blank page.

Comment: So, something is making that call not look like an ajax one. If you remove `if (Request::ajax()) {` it will shut down your application.

Comment: Yep. I removed the 'if(Request::ajax()) {' part and it shut it down. So, is it still using the ajax to call that route? Like I said, I don't know much on the ajax side of things, so still learning about it. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Yes, it is still using Ajax in your Javascript, but Laravel is not being able to understand that this is a ajax call. If it makes no difference for you, you can leave the way it is now.

Comment: It's working correctly now. Looking in my console it's grabbing the right routes for both up and down. Thanks!